# Is there an equivalent to localStorage in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, local-storage

I'd like to implement the equivalent to the javascript localStorage in my React Native app. But I'm unsure how to set. To function how I want it to, I would like the localStorage to be stored every time the app opens. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Async Storage - https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Secure Storage (Expo) - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/securestore/

Comment: Thank you!! I've done it by the first option.

Comment: Cool. Glad it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

A better option than React Native Async Storage these days is [React Native MMKV](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv). It includes support for **synchronously** getting/setting strings, booleans and numbers.

Read more about why MMKV is recommended over Async Storage [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/stop-using-react-native-async-storage-fdbcc05a6de3).

Answer (score 0):

In React Native applications, data can be persisted locally using AsyncStorage .

[You can check it out here.](https://muralimahadeva.medium.com/react-native-local-storage-options-asyncstorage-e6ea80931bc0)